# How to test if two codes give exactly the same output for any input

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I've been solving some questions in python at college.

Unfortunately the system we use for submition don't give exactly which tests we failed.

That makes impossible to find out where my logic is wrong even if I have a solution in my hand.

I never used testing and I not even know how it works, but I'd like to know if there is any way to find out if two codes give exactly the same output for any input I give. So I can get the solutions and find out where I did wrong.

PS: I'm not cheating, I'm just getting the provided solutions at the end of the tests and trying to understand where my logic is wrong, so I can do better in the next ones.

For example:
in this leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/

This was my solution:

```
prefix = ['I', 'X', 'C']
value = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}

def rec(s, v):
    n = s[0:1]
    if len(s) > 1 and n in prefix and value[s[0:1]] < value[s[1:2]]:
        n = s[0:2]
    if len(n) > 1:
        v += value[n[1]] - value[n[0]]
    else:
        v += value[n]
    s = s.removeprefix(n)
    return v if not s else rec(s, v)


class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        return (rec(s, 0))
```

But I solved As well with this other code:

```
class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        prefix = ['I', 'X', 'C']
        value = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}

        v = 0
        while s:
            n = s[0:1]
            if len(s) > 1 and n in prefix and value[s[0:1]] < value[s[1:2]]:
                n = s[0:2]
            if len(n) > 1:
                v += value[n[1]] - value[n[0]]
            else:
                v += value[n]
            print(s, n, v)
            s = s.removeprefix(n)
        return v
```

Let's say that I couldn't solve it, but I have the solution, How could I compare if the output for my code in progress is the same of the solution ? So I can check where I'm doing wrong in my logic.

Comment: Typically you would create a proof to generalize the output of a function or to prove its correctness for all given input.

Comment: Okay, but how to do that, can you give an example?

Comment: @Mark Proofs are good, but if even Knuth said "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it"... Also, sometimes I see someone's answer here and I just "know" it's wrong but have difficulty proving it, in which case I sometimes employ the same technique: generate inputs and compare my solution's results with theirs, to find an example input I can show them where they fail.

Comment: @KellyBundy,  I think you got what I meant. The problem is, how can I generate inputs if my tests are correct for all possible inputs I can think of and I not even know where I'm doing wrong? Is there a framework, or tool to do that? Maybe  some tool to generate random inputs So I can compare might solve.

Comment: I usually do random inputs, or *all* possible inputs, or all possible inputs up to some "size" (or up to a failure). I don't know a general tool, I write new code each time.

Comment: No argument @KellyBundy — I am certainly not making proofs for code I write. I guess the point I was trying to make is that to *know* how a function behaves depends on being able to generalize and make a mental model of the logic. Unless the function operates over a discrete, limited domain there isn't a useful way to look at all output.

Comment: Both of those solutions are correct, right? Not a good example then for what you're asking...

Comment: I realize looking at my first comment, I really misused the term `typically`. Generating proofs is not typical. On the other hand, demonstrating that two functions give *exactly* the same output for *any* input is also not typical. You will generally be mixing known generalizations and logic to feel comfortable about the correctness, and writing tests that support these assumptions and test edge cases. But even known and edge case is an edge case requires understanding the logical assumptions you are making.

Answer (score 2):

## To answer your general question

This goes into a large topics in testing methodologies and strategies. I'll give a short list of different testing techniques that can achieve different goals that are related to what you're looking for. Google to find out more.

#### Example/Case testing

Manually select testcases to test -- most common/natural test. Typically choose cases that represent ideal use-cases as well as known edge cases. Simple, reproducible, but weak to missing cases you didn't consider.

#### Property testing

Conceptually test the invariant constraints of a system rather than specific cases, e.g. for addition, you'd test that `2 + 3 == 3 + 2` (commutative), `(2 + 3) + 4 == 2 + (3 + 4)` (associative), and that zero is the addition identity. These tests work regardless of any specific case, so test cases could even be generated.

#### Exhaustive testing

Computers are finite machines after all. It's possible to enumerate some/most/all possible inputs. E.g. 8-bit integer addition can be exhaustively tested in 256 * 256 = 65,536 cases. Can become extremely (exponentially) expensive and impractical.

#### Fuzzing

Throwing random input into the system under test to see if there are previously uncovered edge cases.

#### Mutation testing

Tests the coverage of your tests by randomly modifying the system under test and confirming that tests fail.

## To solve your specific issue with that leetcode problem

To be 99% exhaustive, you could use a combination of the first 3 I listed above.

1. Example testing: test basic cases, then more complex ones.
2. Property testing: write a number to roman numeral, test that the two conversions perfectly reverse each other.
3. Exhaustive testing: test all numbers from 1 to some big number with your number to roman numeral. Computers are fast, you can probably get to 1M at least.

Comment: Thank you Kache, I knew my question needed some anshwer related to testing, I searched about it, but I not even knew where to start. And looking on youtube, I found out this subject really hard to find good material explaining it :/

Comment: I think Exaustive testing might be the better solution for my case, I'm gonna see how to apply that on pytest, thank you for the tip.

Comment: 2./3. is what I did, except instead of writing my own intToRoman, I copied one from LeetCode (which of course has both directions of the problem :-).